# How to replace a character \ in java

Tags: java

I just wanted to replace sequence of a character **'\'** (i.e. consecutive like \\\) to single **'\'** in Java. If possible I dont want to iterate with for loop all. Is there anything possible with regex to find and replace? Because in my case I will get lots of input like this if user gave in application for each and every time I have to validate and replace all \ character.

Can anyone help me in this context.

input is : **\\\\Program Files\\Microsoft Games\\\\\Chess\\\Chess.exe**

output which I expect is : **\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Chess\Chess.exe**

Comment: Lets say the variable name of the String is `str` then do the following `str.replace("\\\\\\","\\");`

Comment: Your input looks strange.  Does your input actually have 3 backslashes?

Comment: @SteelToe I cannot predict that the user will give \\\\\\ (i.e. total 6 \ alone) I have to change, if user give even 10 total number of backslashes also.

Comment: `str.replaceAll("\\+", "\\")`.

Comment: @AntonH No, that won't work, because backslash has a semantic meaning in regex and `String#replaceAll()` accepts a regex pattern.

Comment: I have tried with String.replaceAll() but I dont know whether I have made any mistakes in Regex but that doesn't work. But the answer given below has worked well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, I forgot to double-escape them ... shmosel didn't forget, though, so it's all good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static String replaceConsecutiveBackslash(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\\\{2,}", "\\\\");
}
```

Comment: @shmosel Why not use the + quantifier?

Comment: @SteelToe `+` matches 1 or more. We only need to deal with 2 or more.